# Como ordenar por média e quantidade (peso)?

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho essa query no **MySql**:

```
SELECT
    dealers.id,
    COALESCE (AVG(rating), 0) AS media,
    COALESCE (COUNT(dealer_ratings.id), 0) AS qtd_avaliacoes
FROM
    `dealers`
LEFT JOIN `dealer_ratings` ON `dealer_ratings`.`id_concessionaria` = `dealers`.`id`
AND `id_status` IN (1, 2)
WHERE
    `id_cidade` = 5141
AND `confirmada` = 1
GROUP BY
    `dealers`.`id`
ORDER BY
    `media` DESC,
    `qtd_avaliacoes` DESC
```

Me traz esse resultado:

```
ID      Média   Quantidade
11393   5.0000      1
12291   4.5000      12
11918   0.0000      0
14078   0.0000      0
```

Eu não posso ordenar por *MEDIA* e *QTD_AVALIACOES* e nem ao contrário, *QTD_AVALICOES* e *MEDIA*. Caso eu faço em uma dessas maneiras, pode dar certo em alguns casos e não em outros.

Portanto, preciso ordenar por peso da média. Mas não sei que cálculo fazer.

No caso do exemplo acima, o resultado com média 4,5 e 12 de quantidade seria para estar em primeiro, porquê proporcionalmente é melhor.

Como faço isso ?

Comment: Quer ordenar pelo resultado MEDIA*QTD_AVALIACOES em cada linha certo?

Comment: Quero fazer média ponderada, se não me engano. Não sei explicar, sou newbie.

Comment: Não diga isso. Ok mas que calculo é? MEDIA*QTD_AVALIACOES em cada linha? que operação matemática quer fazer para depois ordenar?

Comment: Quero calcular o peso da média. Acredito que seja isso que você falou.

Comment: Mas qual peso? O que é o peso?... Vou colocar uma pssível solução para o problema, se não for diga para retirar a  resposta

Comment: Por que removeu a resposta @Miguel. Tinha me ajudado.

Comment: Ha peço desculpa, pensei que estivesse errada e que não isso que queria... Vou colocar

Comment: É que eu estou fazendo testes, por isso não dei feedback.

Comment: Ok, já está. Peço desculpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se isto resolve, multiplicar a `media` por a `qtd_avaliacoes` respetiva:

```
SELECT (AVG(rating), 0)*(COUNT(dealer_ratings.id), 0) as result FROM dealers ORDER BY result DESC;
```

Adaptado ao seu caso:

```
SELECT
    dealers.id,
    COALESCE (AVG(rating), 0) AS media,
    COALESCE (COUNT(dealer_ratings.id), 0) AS qtd_avaliacoes,
    (AVG(rating), 0)*(COUNT(dealer_ratings.id), 0) as result
FROM
    `dealers`
LEFT JOIN `dealer_ratings` ON `dealer_ratings`.`id_concessionaria` = `dealers`.`id`
AND `id_status` IN (1, 2)
WHERE
    `id_cidade` = 5141
AND `confirmada` = 1
GROUP BY
    `dealers`.`id`
ORDER BY result DESC;
```

Comment: Isso dá erro: **Unknown column 'media' in 'field list'**

Comment: Ha desculpe... Distração da minha parte @DiegoSouza. Vou emendar

Comment: É que eu não consigo votar pra cima porquê não tenho 15 pontos de reputação. Mas funcionou o que você falou. Não havia pensado nisso. Obrigado

Comment: Não tem importância @DiegoSouza, Obgado, quando tiver vota ;P

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma seria:

```
SELECT
    dealers.id,
    COALESCE (AVG(rating), 0) AS media,
    COALESCE (COUNT(dealer_ratings.id), 0) AS qtd_avaliacoes 
FROM  `dealers` 
    LEFT JOIN `dealer_ratings` ON `dealer_ratings`.`id_concessionaria` = `dealers`.`id` AND `id_status` IN (1, 2)         
WHERE
    `id_cidade` = 5141 AND `confirmada` = 1 
GROUP BY
    `dealers`.`id` 
ORDER BY
    COALESCE (AVG(rating), 0)  DESC,
    COALESCE (COUNT(dealer_ratings.id), 0) DESC
```

Ou seja, é exatamente a sua `query`, alterei apenas o `order by`.

Comment: Ainda não é isso. Eu fiz dessa forma na minha query acima.